# How To Change /Lib Directory

Tags: linux, hard-drive, unix, filesystems, performance-tuning

Production server / is only 50GB and it's full.

23GB is in /lib | /snapd 11GB /flatpak 7GB

I see the snap store is installing snaps to /var/lib/snapd | I have a second drive /dev/sdb that has 500GB of space available.  sdb is a 500GB ssd .

Is it possible to tell the Snapstore to install snaps to /dev/sdb? or just move /lib to sdb?
I was thinking something like

`mount --rbind /var/lib/snapd/ /mnt/sdb/snapd/` |

I don't have proper backups in place atm

Open to any other solutions as well.  Thanks for responses.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic. We don't accept home computing questions. You may be able to get help on one of our sister sites, such as [ubuntu.se], [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: This isn't a home computing question this is a production server in a live environment.  Nothing off topic here.